# functions to execute command and print output

Tags: c

When I print buf than strange chars appears

```
void excmd(const char* cmd, ...) {
    char buf[100];
    va_list args;
    va_start(args,cmd); 
    snprintf(buf,strlen(buf),cmd,args);
    printf("%s",buf); // just here to debug // I also want to use my own print instead of it but it won't works
    system(buf);
    va_end(args);
    /* calling it like excmd("echo %s",files) */
}
```

Also this doesn't works

```
#define mprintf(fmt,...) fprintf(stderr,"\033[2K " fmt " \033[0m\n", ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: You forgot the format — so the command is used as the format.

Comment: Answer Below answer doesn't works

Comment: Yes, because of the reason I said in my comment.

Comment: Not working man

Comment: Saying "not working" does not say very much — in what way is it not working?  What does it do?  What does it not do?  What is it supposed to do?  How were we to know given that you've not shown us how you are (mis?)using the code?  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  **Note** there's a comment about how you call it — the first thing that is ignored is comments because comments are always wrong! Show us the code in working form. — Note too that `snprintf()` should be `vsnprintf()`; `snprintf()` doesn't handle an argument of type `va_list`.  (Also note `strlen()` vs `sizeof`.)

Comment: Also, it is not clear what you are asking about `mprintf()`.  It's a macro; in what way doesn't it work?  What does it do instead of working?  How do you call it?  Show us your code!  We can't fix what we can't see.

Comment: thanks man that vsnprintf worked thanks a lot

Comment: Hey I want buf variable to be dynamic and depend on sizeof (cmd+args) how can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you have `vasprintf()` available?  If so, use it. Otherwise, call `sprintf()` twice: once with zero length to find out how much space you need to get allocate and once after you’ve allocated it.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `strlen` on an uninitialized buffer, which is undefined behaviour.

`strlen` finds the length of a string by incrementing a pointer from the start of the string to the null-terminator. If your buffer is uninitialized, it may well go out of bounds in search of one.

Replace `strlen` with `sizeof` in your `snprintf` call.  Also replace `snprintf()` with `vsnprintf()`.